# Is "autonym" an autonym?

Tags: axioms, first-order-logic

I believe this is set theory, but I don't really know set theory, so...

An autonym is a word that refers to a property that the word itself happens to possess. For example "noun" is an autonym because "noun" is a noun. "Word" is an autonym. "Pentasyllabic" is too. "Poop" is not, unless you can poop words. (I can't.)

So. Is "autonym" an autonym? If you can't prove "yes" or "no" exclusively, does that make it a restatement of some axiom of set theory?

Comment: Call a word, which is not an autonym a "nautonym". Is "nautonym" a nautonym?

Comment: Not every statement without a well-defined truth value is an axiom of set theory. But self-reference is indeed at the heart of many issues in set theory. Look up Russell's Paradox for a famous example, and if you're ambitious take a look at Hofstadter's book "Gödel, Escher, Bach."

Comment: "'Poop' is not..." I don't know. I mean, have you *been* on the Internet?

Comment: @JakobWerner I should have added that I tend to ignore unresolvable paradoxes. It's this tautological weirdness that trips me up.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip So then what determines what achieves axiom status and what doesn't? Or maybe that's deserves a separate Question.

Comment: This problem has already been discussed ... See [Grelling–Nelson paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox).

Comment: Great question. Clearly no answer but very fun and interesting.

Comment: Also @MackTuesday While an axiom is any statement that a mathematician uses as a basic assumption of their theory, there is a certain set of statements which are widely used as axioms. These are what most people are talking about when referring to axioms.